# jquery each to loop and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some span tags:

```
<span w="560"></span>
<span w="340"></span>
<span w="120"></span>
```

With jQuery, I want to select EACH span, get the value inside its w attribute and animate it to that value + "px".

I have a simple code that didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('span').animate({width: $(this).attr('w') + 'px'}, 2000);

});
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: even in HTML5 is the `'w'` attribute valid? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**this** does not make any sense with no context .

Use `$.each loop` and your code should work as **this** will refer to the  current span in the iteration

```
$('span').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('w') + 'px'}, 2000);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

As `adeneo` suggested , your HTML will not be validated while using custom attributes. Prepend it with data so that your HTML will be validated as well..

```
<span data-w="560"></span>
```

To access it you can use

`$(this).data('w');`    **OR**  `$(this).attr('data-w')`

Comment: here it works perfectly! but is there a way to make them animate one after the other and not together? and is there a way to make the animation time depend on the target width of each span so that a span that will be 200px takes 2000ms and that of 50px takes only 500ms?

Comment: For animating one after another use can queue them up ... Also you can dynamically set the time based on the width .. Calculate the width of the span.. It is 200px the set a variable to 2000 and use that variable in the animate method

Answer (score 2):

Use a valid attribute, like data-w:

```
<span data-w="560"></span>
<span data-w="340"></span>
<span data-w="120"></span>
```

and iterate over the elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('span').each(function(idx, elm) {
        $(elm).animate({width: $(elm).data('w')}, 2000);
    });

});
```